# How to save an active record object when its association has been deleted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-console

I have a model named Company along with many associations, and it's an association having many more. (with dependent destroy)

```
com = Company.find_by(name: 'ABC')
```

I then destroy the entry by

```
Company.find_by(name: 'ABC').destroy
```

Now '`com`' has the record, and when I perform `com.save` the object does not get stored along with its association.

**Note**
I am trying to debug as to where my destroy query is taking time (it has hundreds of associations), so I don't want to lose the data, I want to save it in the console after debugging.

Comment: I don't understand. You want to re-create deleted record?

Comment: @user that is not the way to debug. You loose data already unless you have soft delete enabled by some gems. Next time, open rails console in sandbox mode. Like `rails c --sandbox` t avoid such disasters..

Comment: @MarekLipka I don't have enough data locally, so I want to debug it on staging server. And so I don't want to delete the data permanently, just temporarily till I figure out what is slowing the query.

Comment: pull your staging server into dev. it's good to have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best approach would be to, one way or another, wrap the action in a **database transaction**. You can then *rollback* the transaction to restore all the data to its original state.

To write this explicitly, you could do something like:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  Company.find_by(name: 'ABC').destroy
  # Any debugging can be done here, or above
  raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
end
```

In fact, rails actually provides a [debugging tool for precisely this use case](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-console): You can make any changes to the database and have everything rolled back (inside a transaction, like above) by running:

```
rails console --sandbox
```

Comment: Perfect ! This is exactly what I was looking for : D Thanks mate.